# Android/iOS/Win: force browser to save HTML/JS/CSS indefinitely

Tags: html, caching, mobile, browser

We're going to create a data-driven mobile HTML5 app. I was thinking we can just access it using the default browser on each platform. I read about caching behavior of browsers on latest versions of iOS and Android, but wasn't able to find any information about the possibility of telling the browser, by using some sort of headers or whatever, to store a particular resource, HTML or JS or CSS or an image, indefinitely in cache until a certain date, for ex. Is that even possible?

The idea here is users open the application regularly but not often. Their browsing will fill the cache with other data; we need to "pin" or "anchor" our app to stay there despite cache being filled, like "higher priority".

Any other suggestions would be welcome (ie., creating a "shell" native app, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links answered the question:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/#toc-updating-cache